# why some thin character roboto ?

Tags: css, fonts, roboto

ı use "roboto" and "san-serif" ,normal text "A.Ş" error text  -->   [image]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: you need to look at the cahracter set of your font - it probably doesn't have the one that appears wrong and therefore a replacement is being used

Comment: this char exist in turkish languge and it looks like roboto support it:https://www.blogarti.com/turkce-karakter-uyumlu-en-iyi-google-webfontlar.html

Comment: @לבנימלכה OP may not have downloaded the turkish package though - they would need to check their charset - it's impossible from the information provided to tell what the problem is

Comment: @Pete see my answer it looks like it works for me

Comment: @לבנימלכה Is OP using googleapi for their fonts though - again we would need to see how OP is adding their font face - they obviously don't have that character otherwise it would render properly

Answer (score 2):

It's because your font doesn't have that character (Ş), so it uses the default font that has it. And if *san-serif* isn't a typo here, you should change it to *sans-serif*.

Comment: if it turkish so `roboto` has this char:https://www.blogarti.com/turkce-karakter-uyumlu-en-iyi-google-webfontlar.html

Comment: I know that Roboto is multilingual, but I wrote that _his_ font doesn't have it. To use multiple charsets in this font if you are importing from Google Fonts, you must choose the right language package when importing, basically add the `subset=latin-ext` as another parameter to the link (I don't know really know if it is in the latin extended subset)

Comment: Well, it wasn't my question tho, and I don't have that problem

Answer (score 0):

Use fonts from [googleapis](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) and it will work

```css
   body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 48px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
 <p>A.Ş</p>
```